# Apply .mtl without re-rendering .obj in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have multiple mtl files and one obj file, whenever I apply different mtl, I need to reload obj as well which is kind of creepy in terms of performance, is there any way I can apply mtl to obj (change mtl) without reloading obj?

Comment: Can you share your code or current work progress? In this way it's easier to provide your some help.

Comment: var mtlLoader1 = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader1.setPath("");


        mtlLoader1.load(mtl, function (materials) {

            materials.preload();

            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('');
            objLoader.load(obj, function (object) {
                THREE.Cache.add('file',object);
                scene.add(object);
                object.position.y = 5;
                object.name = "objectone";

            }, onProgress, onError);
        });

Comment: function load_other_file() {

      var selectedObject = scene.getObjectByName('objectone');

    console.log(selectedObject);

        var mtl = '03_Int_Ext with JetPaks/A7_with_JetPaks.mtl';

Comment: now i want to apply another mtl file to existing object to change its color